Fastest way to create a new df from an inconsistent data source
I'm facing an issue with an API that provides responses with varying numbers of fields. Despite the API offering a total of 106 fields, response items often contain different numbers of fields due to data availability (a subset of the total 106).
So a fresh dataframe that needs populating maybe data['items'][0] has a 28 of 106 fields/values and data['items'][1] has 100 of 106.
I cannot find a way to benefit from the various Pandas optimisations when importing data, and simply do for example:
df = pd.DataFrame(data['items'])
df.columns = data['headers']

Which generates a length mismatch

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 55 elements, new values have 106 elements

To work around this, I first create an empty dataframe with the correct headers and then append each item individually. However, this method proves inefficient for large datasets (250,000+)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=data['headers'])

for item in data['items']:
    item_series = pd.Series(item, index=data['fields'])
    df = pd.concat([df, item_series.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)

I'm seeking advice on a more efficient approach to handle this discrepancy and improve dataframe instantiation and updating processes. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Data snapshot which I have anonymised:
d = {
  "headers": [
    "Header 1",
    "Header 2",
    "Header 3",
    "Header 4",
    "Header 5",
    "Header 6",
    "Header 7",
    "Header 8",
    "Header 9",
    "Header 10",
    "Header 11",
    "Header 12",
    "Header 13",
    "Header 14",
    "Header 15",
    "Header 16",
    "Header 17",
    "Header 18",
    "Header 19",
    "Header 20",
    "Header 21",
    "Header 22",
    "Header 23",
    "Header 24",
    "Header 25",
    "Header 26",
    "Header 27",
    "Header 28",
    "Header 29",
    "Header 30",
    "Header 31",
    "Header 32",
    "Header 33",
    "Header 34",
    "Header 35",
    "Header 36",
    "Header 37",
    "Header 38",
    "Header 39",
    "Header 40",
    "Header 41",
    "Header 42",
    "Header 43",
    "Header 44",
    "Header 45",
    "Header 46",
    "Header 47",
    "Header 48",
    "Header 49",
    "Header 50",
    "Header 51",
    "Header 52",
    "Header 53",
    "Header 54",
    "Header 55",
    "Header 56",
    "Header 57",
    "Header 58",
    "Header 59",
    "Header 60",
    "Header 61",
    "Header 62",
    "Header 63",
    "Header 64",
    "Header 65",
    "Header 66",
    "Header 67",
    "Header 68",
    "Header 69",
    "Header 70",
    "Header 71",
    "Header 72",
    "Header 73",
    "Header 74",
    "Header 75",
    "Header 76",
    "Header 77",
    "Header 78",
    "Header 79",
    "Header 80",
    "Header 81",
    "Header 82",
    "Header 83",
    "Header 84",
    "Header 85",
    "Header 86",
    "Header 87",
    "Header 88",
    "Header 89",
    "Header 90",
    "Header 91",
    "Header 92",
    "Header 93",
    "Header 94",
    "Header 95",
    "Header 96",
    "Header 97",
    "Header 98",
    "Header 99",
    "Header 100",
    "Header 101",
    "Header 102",
    "Header 103",
    "Header 104",
    "Header 105",
    "Header 106"
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "Header 17": "anon1",
      "Header 27": "anon2",
      "Header 28": "anon3",
      "Header 29": "anon4",
      "Header 32": "anon5",
      "Header 33": "anon6",
      "Header 34": "anon7",
      "Header 35": "anon8",
      "Header 36": "anon9",
      "Header 37": "anon10",
      "Header 38": "anon11",
      "Header 39": "anon12",
      "Header 40": "anon13",
      "Header 46": "anon14",
      "Header 50": "anon15",
      "Header 52": "anon16",
      "Header 53": "anon17",
      "Header 55": "anon18",
      "Header 56": "anon19",
      "Header 57": "anon20",
      "Header 58": "anon21",
      "Header 59": "anon22",
      "Header 61": "anon23",
      "Header 62": "anon24",
      "Header 63": "anon25",
      "Header 67": "anon26",
      "Header 68": "anon27",
      "Header 71": "anon28",
      "Header 73": "anon29",
      "Header 75": "anon30",
      "Header 76": "anon31",
      "Header 80": "anon32",
      "Header 81": "anon33",
      "Header 82": "anon34",
      "Header 83": "anon35",
      "Header 84": "anon36",
      "Header 85": "anon37",
      "Header 87": "anon38",
      "Header 88": "anon39",
      "Header 89": "anon40",
      "Header 91": "anon41",
      "Header 92": "anon42",
      "Header 94": "anon43",
      "Header 96": "anon44",
      "Header 97": "anon45",
      "Header 99": "anon46",
      "Header 105": "anon47"
    }
  ],
}


Please give a reproducible example of data (or data['items'] if the rest is not relevant).

@mozway great suggestion, thank you. I have updated the original message with an anonymised snapshot.

Simply pass the headers to the DataFrame constructor:
pd.DataFrame(data['items'], columns=data['headers'])

If for some reason you have to instantiate without the names, then reindex afterwards:
df = pd.DataFrame(data['items'])
df = df.reindex(columns=data['headers'])

Output:
   Header 1  Header 2  Header 3  Header 4  Header 5  Header 6  Header 7  Header 8  Header 9  Header 10  Header 11  Header 12  Header 13  Header 14  Header 15  Header 16 Header 17  Header 18  Header 19  Header 20  Header 21  Header 22  Header 23  Header 24  Header 25  Header 26 Header 27 Header 28 Header 29  Header 30  Header 31 Header 32 Header 33 Header 34 Header 35 Header 36 Header 37 Header 38 Header 39 Header 40  Header 41  Header 42  Header 43  Header 44  Header 45 Header 46  Header 47  Header 48  Header 49 Header 50  Header 51 Header 52 Header 53  Header 54 Header 55 Header 56 Header 57 Header 58 Header 59  Header 60 Header 61 Header 62 Header 63  Header 64  Header 65  Header 66 Header 67 Header 68  Header 69  Header 70 Header 71  Header 72 Header 73  Header 74 Header 75 Header 76  Header 77  Header 78  Header 79 Header 80 Header 81 Header 82 Header 83 Header 84 Header 85  Header 86 Header 87 Header 88 Header 89  Header 90 Header 91 Header 92  Header 93 Header 94  Header 95 Header 96 Header 97  Header 98 Header 99  Header 100  Header 101  Header 102  Header 103  Header 104 Header 105  Header 106
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN     anon1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN     anon2     anon3     anon4        NaN        NaN     anon5     anon6     anon7     anon8     anon9    anon10    anon11    anon12    anon13        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN    anon14        NaN        NaN        NaN    anon15        NaN    anon16    anon17        NaN    anon18    anon19    anon20    anon21    anon22        NaN    anon23    anon24    anon25        NaN        NaN        NaN    anon26    anon27        NaN        NaN    anon28        NaN    anon29        NaN    anon30    anon31        NaN        NaN        NaN    anon32    anon33    anon34    anon35    anon36    anon37        NaN    anon38    anon39    anon40        NaN    anon41    anon42        NaN    anon43        NaN    anon44    anon45        NaN    anon46         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     anon47         NaN

